# Android: Unable to build APK. More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version'

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle, jwplayer

All of a sudden, I am getting this error while building APK

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDevDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version'
```

I went through a lot of StackOverflow post related to `META-INF` issue such as `exclude 'META-INF/***' (LICENSE, NOTICE` etc etc) in `packagingOptions` but it's not working. I have uninstalled Java 9 also and installed JDK8. Here is the output when I run with `--stacktrace` option

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDevDebug]

Parallel execution with configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDevDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDevDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:greendaoPrepare UP-TO-DATE
:app:greendao UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/shikhardeep/StudioProjects/HOGAndroid_New/app/src/debug/google-services.json
:app:mergeDevDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDevDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:dataBindingExportBuildInfoDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDevDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDevDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDevDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDevDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDevDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDevDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDevDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDevDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDevDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:311)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:202)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:107)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version'
    at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$acceptOnlyOne$2(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:75)
    at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms.lambda$select$3(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:100)
    at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMergerOutputs$1.create(IncrementalFileMergerOutputs.java:86)
    at com.android.builder.merge.DelegateIncrementalFileMergerOutput.create(DelegateIncrementalFileMergerOutput.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MergeJavaResourcesTransform$1.create(MergeJavaResourcesTransform.java:379)
    at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger.updateChangedFile(IncrementalFileMerger.java:221)
    at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger.mergeChangedInputs(IncrementalFileMerger.java:190)
    at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger.merge(IncrementalFileMerger.java:77)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MergeJavaResourcesTransform.transform(MergeJavaResourcesTransform.java:411)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 102 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s

28 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 26 up-to-date
```

**This is my app/build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    maven { url 'http://static.clmbtech.com/maven' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<package_ID>"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 63
        versionName "2.2.8"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'jsr305_annotations/Jsr305_annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'error_prone/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Annotations.gwt.xml'
        exclude 'third_party/java_src/error_prone/project/annotations/Google_internal.gwt.xml'
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        maxProcessCount 8
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
            resConfigs "en", "xxhdpi"
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }

        prod {

        }
    }
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 1
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //All Dependencies 
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'

    implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:+'
    implementation 'com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:+'
    implementation('com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-ima:+') {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }

    implementation 'com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When i searched for this file: `META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version` I get 2 locations:

```
/Users/shikhardeep/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/runtime-1.1.0.aar/f7273cc34aac547da4a88fd1c25f0f2f/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version

/Users/shikhardeep/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3/interactivemedia/3.8.2/abbc5b12ce9ca95049dce9a22cfe7a7f6709aaee/interactivemedia-3.8.2.jar!/META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version
```

and both of them only contains a value `1.1.0`

One more thing: for this dependency `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'` I am getting this warning `All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version` for a last couple of months. I don't think so this is the root cause of build failure as I was able to build APK (dev as well as release) till yesterday. There is no change in gradle file except `versionCode` and `versionName` (which I increment after a release).

**UPDATE 1:**
I have solved that `All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version` by adding these but still the error persists

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0'
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I found this GitHub issue and it seems similar to my case: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3911.
I followed the approach mentioned by one of the commentator Victor Raft and now I am able to build but I am not sure whether it's the right way or not.

**UPDATE 3:** 
Although build was successful but I noticed that I am not able to play most of the media URLs. Same media URLs are working fine on live App. I am using JWPlayer SDK for media streaming. Everytime I open the VideoActivity, I get `onError()` callback with error message:  `Invalid HTTP response code: 404: Not Found`. According to JWPlayer changelog: https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/about/release-notes/ they have updated the SDK on Mar21, 2018 and since that day I am also getting the error. In the SDK setup instructions https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/android/docs/developer-guide/getting-started/library-project-setup/ they have recommended to use + while including dependencies. If I try to build by specifying a lower version (2.8.0) in gradle. I get an error while syncing: `Failed to resolve: com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:2.8.0`

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `pickFirst` something like this:

```
packagingOptions {
   // this is the lazy option.
   //pickFirst  'META-INF/*'
   pickFirst   'META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version'
}
```

Comment: I have posted UPDATE 2. Looks like issue from Google/Exoplayer side. github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3911.

Answer (score 2):

**In my case**, I've excluded only path 'META-INF/LICENSE' on `yourProject/app/build.gradle` inside `android{}` . Here it is

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

After it Clean Project and Rebuild Project.

**If above case doesn't work** for you then You can add this in `yourProject/app/build.gradle` inside `android{}`

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

Comment: I have already tried excluding lots of META-INF/*** but it doesn't work. Looks like issue from Google/Exoplayer side. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3911.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution per Detox android setup guide:

You need to add this to the android section of your `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

reference https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.Android.md#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

In buil.gradule ( module ) include under {android  ... and before default configuration this line
android.packagingOptions.resources.pickFirsts += "**/*.pickFirst"