# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-architecture-lifecycle

I have the following error while building my APK.

```
Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version
    File1: /Users/.../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-base/12.0.0/jars/classes.jar
    File2: /Users/.../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/android.arch.lifecycle/runtime/1.1.1/jars/classes.jar
```

The dependencies added in app build.gradle are as follows

```
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:12.0.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:12.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version
>
> File1: /Users/.../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-base/12.0.0/jars/classes.jar
>
> File2: /Users/.../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/android.arch.lifecycle/runtime/1.1.1/jars/classes.jar

It says that it found two files with the same library, one in your first compile :

```
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1"
```

And then another one in

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0"
```

That's because `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.0` already contains `lifecycle:runtime` just remove the first line and then rebuild/clean the project again.

If it did not work just exclude this in your `gradle.build` as pointed in [this issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3911)

```
exclude 'META-INF/android.arch.lifecycle_runtime.version'
exclude 'META-INF/com.android.support_support-v4.version'
exclude 'META-INF/com.android.support_support-fragment.version'
exclude 'META-INF/com.android.support_support-media-compat.version'
exclude 'META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-utils.version'
exclude 'META-INF/com.android.support_support-compat.version'
exclude 'META-INF/com.android.support_support-core-ui.version'
```

Plus you can take a look on this problem too : [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49423572/android-unable-to-build-apk-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-p)